# Can't connect to http://localhost:3000 on Safari browser

Tags: reactjs, safari, localhost, macos-big-sur

I can't connect to http://localhost:3000 on Safari browser. Could anyone help?

```
Summary
URL: https://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
localhost:28
```

[image]